# List of sites with SSL 3.0

Tags: ssl

I am trying to debug something and I would need a list of sites with SSL v3.0 (old version of SSL) to test something. Is it possible to get a list of some of those sites? If you know of any of them, can you please add it as an answer?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could probably browse some of the recent results on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html that had low scores...

Comment: @ceejayoz: that's an excellent tip. thanks! add it as an answer so I can up vote you if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably browse some of the recent results on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html that had low scores.